# Unable to make websocket connection from webapp's JS when using Latchet framework deployed on CentOS server

Tags: php, linux, laravel, websocket, centos

We are developing a webapp on Laravel framework to be deployed on CentOS linux server. For updates pushable from server to the browser, we are using [Latchet](https://github.com/sidneywidmer/Latchet). We did the development on the Windows machine, and on there our webapp side (HTML/JS on browser) is able to make connections to the websocket server (Latchet), and hence successfully getting the server push notifications. The problem is that, when we do the actual deployment on our staging server on CentOS, the webapp side is not being able to make the websocket connection with the Latchet server.

We have checked all the dependencies, firewall, and network settings. We also telnet to the exposed websocket IP and port, and it connects with no issue. My suspicion is in the some configuration we are missing rite now.

Comment: Are you getting an error of any sort?  Do you think whatever is causing your issues could be because Latchet is not even considered alpha yet and not to be used in production?

Comment: Well on the webapp JS side, we are unable to get websocket connection. The call is failing. And its only happening when we deploy the solution on CentOS, whereas when deployed on Windows, the same code (JS and backend Laravel server side code) works.

Answer (score 0):

it turn out the issue was only due to port blocking by the local firewall. Thus as soon as I stopped the iptables and ip6tables services, my issue immediately resolved.